# Using an accepted connection as a socket (cpp-netlib)

Tags: c++, http, boost, tcp, connection

Is it possible to get an accepted connection via [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/) and use it like a normal TCP `Boost.asio` socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `socket_` member of `boost::network::http::impl::http_async_connection` is private, but that would be the member that contains the TCP socket you're looking for, so the short answer is "no"

Comment: So if we use boost::network::http::impl::http_async_connection from sources (which we do because it is header only) we can just make that variable public and will get a real asio socket connection?

Comment: @Blender yes, that would work. To get to that, though, you have to go through the pimpl to get the http_async_connection instance; you have to upcast it to http_async_connection and then you'd have to get the `socket_` from there.. - or you could add the necessary accessors to the base class and the connection class whose impl it is.

Answer (score 0):

Direct support is not available.

May be. we need to get SOCKET handle from one library and attach it to the second library's end point(socket).